# How to translate validation messages in magento2

Tags: magento2, inline-translations

I am not able to change the language of "*Require" in magento2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add more details ...please

Comment: I Edit my Question with more details @Ranganathan.S

Answer (score 2):

First Please check your file of the "*Require" word format

it should be in

```
<?php echo $this->__('Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate') ?>
```

if it doesn't work please use below steps

I have created a file to translate English to German

Create folder path for language file

```
app\design\frontend\<theme>\default\locale\de_DE
```

file name

```
translate.csv
```

Here `de_DE` folder for German language

Inside the csv file should be

[image]

And The world which is translated in phtml format is

```
<?php echo $this->__('Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate') ?>
```

Hope this will work..

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, first you have to find out, in which files your validation messages and notes are provided. Make sure those texts are provided inside the `$this->__()` function. Then make sure you have added respective translation texts in your translation csv file.